# Mix count and exist in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose that we have a table and save on it customerid and orderid.

What is the best approach for take *count of all order* and *check exist of certain customerid* in **one query** ?

I know that this query is wrong but I forced write that because Stackoverflow did not allow me post short question!

For example :

(table name tbTest)

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ORDERID), 
    EXIST(SELECT ID FROM tbTest WHERE customerid = {n}) 
FROM tbTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the follwoing

```
SELECT  COUNT(ORDERID),
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM tbTest WHERE customerid = {n}) then 'Exist'  
            ELSE 'Not Exist'
        END
FROM tbTest
```

Comment: thanks, this is correct, but i have a question. does check sql server case expression for any rows ?

Comment: welcome. i am not sure about the answer of your question but please check with some sample data so that you can sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(OrderID)
FROM dbo.tbTest
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Or maybe

```
DECLARE @CustomerID INT;

SET @CustomerID = 20;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.tbTest
WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID;
```

Comment: in first query first group by customerid then get count of order of customer

Comment: and in your second query get count of customer

Comment: Yes, I know. It's hard to tell from your question what you want.